# Как очистить верстку от JS кода?

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, автоматизация

Есть скаченная из интернета страница с сайта. Нужно очистить весь файл с версткой от JS кода. Как я могу решить этот вопрос в автоматическом режиме?

**До обработки:**

```
    <div class="adm-informer" id="admin-informer" onclick="return BX.adminInformer.OnInnerClick(event);" style="display: none; top:48px; left:316px;">
 <script type="text/javascript">
                             function hideMpAnswer(el, module)
                             {
                               if(el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode)
                                   BX.hide(el.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode);
                               BX.ajax({
                                   'method': 'POST',
                                   'dataType': 'html',
                                   'url': '/bitrix/admin/partner_modules.php',
                                   'data': 'module='+module+'&sessid=7365f247dfe682ee7cd97506e2735c0f&act=unnotify',
                                   'async': true,
                                   'processData': false

                               });
                             }
            </script>
<script>BX.message({'JS_REQUIRED':'Заполните это поле!','JS_FORMAT':'Неверный формат!','JS_FILE_EXT':'Недопустимое расширение файла!','JS_PASSWORD_COPY':'Пароли не совпадают!','JS_PASSWORD_LENGTH':'Минимум 6 символов!','JS_ERROR':'Неверно заполнено поле!','JS_FILE_SIZE':'Максимальный размер 5мб!','JS_FILE_BUTTON_NAME':'Прикрепить файл','JS_FILE_DEFAULT':'Выберите файл','JS_FILE_ADD':'Еще один файл','JS_DATE':'Некорректная дата!','JS_DATETIME':'Некорректная дата/время!','JS_REQUIRED_LICENSES':'Согласитесь с условиями','S_CALLBACK':'Заказать звонок'</script>
```

**После обработки**

```
<div class="adm-informer" id="admin-informer" onclick="" style="display: none; top:48px; left:316px;">
```

Comment: что значит _очистить весь файл с версткой от JS кода_? Добавь пример того что есть и что должно в итоге получиться

Comment: @Grundy, добавил пример

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _автоматическим режимом_? Пройтись по исходникам? или при заходе на страницу в браузере, например?

Comment: @Grundy, только не в ручную

Comment: Можно поиграться с `Content-Security-Policy` при просмотре.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете файл в Notepad++, в меню выбираете "Поиск" -> "Замена..."

В этом пункте меню выбираете "Режим поиска" - "регулярные выражения" и ставите галочку рядом с "и новые строки".

**1.** Чтобы удалить все скрипты в тегах < script >< /script >, в поле "Найти" пишете регулярку:

```
<script (.*?)</script>
```

И нажимаете "Заменить всё".

**2.** Чтобы удалить из тегов onclick, в поле "Найти" пишете регулярку:

```
onclick="(.*?)"
```

И нажимаете "Заменить всё".

Comment: Работает только в Notepad++? Проверил в Sublime 3. Удаляет, но не всё (вариант 1)

Comment: Пример того, что осталось после обработки регулярного выражения, я привел в вопросе, в 
 нижней строке блока "До обработки"

Comment: @Kyper, работает где угодно, если точку заменить на то, что годится для любого символа. И ещё пробел надо заменить на `\b`. Ну и с onclick не всё так просто.

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что непросто с onclick?

Comment: @humster_spb, например, я его могу без кавычек написать) А ещё помимо самого  onclick есть куча всяких onmousedown, onkeypress и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#adm-informer').removeAttr('onclick');
$('script').remove();
```

Comment: Как этим пользоваться?

Comment: @Kyper довольно оригинально))) Подключить jquery и этот скрипт на вашу страницу, выполнить его, а потом скопировать содержимое.... короче это не то, что вам нужно

Comment: Какой вопрос такой и ответ!

Comment: В автоматическрм режиме после скачивания запустить jquery, чтобы обработать скачанные файлы? Что за бред?